# GCD Exponentiation

Tags: python, greatest-common-divisor, exponentiation

I have been trying to determine a shorter method for calculating gcd((a^n + b^n), abs(a-b)). I noticed that, if I were to calculate (using the above formula) say a = 100 and b = 4, starting from 1 and ending at n (a loop), at a certain point, the answer becomes constant. For a = 100, b = 4 and n = 100, I create a loop from 1 to n, and at each point, I apply the formula, the first answer (n = 1) is 8, thereafter it is 32 till when n becomes 100. For optimization, I break out of the loop once two equal consecutive numbers are found and the latest number (32 here), becomes the answer. Does anyone know a straightforward formula for calculating gcd((a^n + b^n), a-b), or better still, my primary concern, a global formula for finding (a^n + b^n)

Note:
1. 1<=a,b,n<=10^12

2. (a^n - b^n) can be simplified as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406703/how-to-simplify-an-bn. But can't find a version for (a^n + b^n)
3. Following Rory Daulton's anwser, I have implemented Exponentiation by Squaring shown below in a function

My Python Code for the above explanation follows suite:

```
a, b, n = map(int, raw_input().split()); ans = -1

if a == b:
    ans = (a**n) + (b**n)

else:
    for j in xrange(n):
        x = gcd((a**n)+(b**n),abs(a-b))

        if x != ans:
            ans = x
        else:
            break
print ans
```

## Exponentiation by Squaring

```
def pow3(x, n):
r = 1
while n:
    if n % 2 == 1:
        r *= x
        n -= 1
    x *= x
    n /= 2
return r
```

Comment: If your "primary concern" is trying to find `a^n + b^n`, what's wrong with just `a**n + b**n`?

Comment: Try computing a^n + b^n, where a, b can be up to 10^10. Takes more than 10 seconds to compute.

Comment: If you're working with very large numbers, you should add the ranges to your question: answers are highly dependent on how large they are.

Comment: in your square-and-multiply algorithm, I would suggest you to use bit operations instead of `n % 2` and `n /= 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways to speed up your code.

First, use the mathematical fact that

```
gcd(r, s) = gcd(r % s, s)
```

(if `s` is not zero). So you do not need to compute `a**n + b**n` in full, you just need it modulo `a - b`. And you can do that by finding `(a**n) % (a-b)` and `(b**n) % (a-b)` then adding those modulo `a - b`.

Now, find `a**n` by the [exponentiation by squaring method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). That involves a loop that executes `log2(n)` times. In each pass through the loop, take the remainder mod `a - b` to keep your numbers low and speed up the calculations.

So there is your algorithm. Find `(a**n) % (a-b)` and `(b**n) % (a-b)` by exponentiation by squaring and modulus at each step. Then add them and take the modulus again. Finally, find the GCD of that value with `a - b`.

---

In some situations, such as `a - b` prime, I can see some shortcuts. The modulus of the powers of a number do repeat, as you note. However, finding out just when they repeat is a non-trivial problem for large values of `a - b`, especially if `a - b` is composite and hard to factor. Unless you have some additional information on the values of `a - b` and your other parameters, I suggest you not use the repetitions. If the values of `a` and `b` are small and known in advance (as in your example of `a = 100` and `b = 4`, the repetitions are more attractive and you could pre-compute the values of powers modulus `96`.

---

**Rather than use this code, you should probably use Python's built-in pow function.** [See here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) for documentation. Hat tip to @DSM.

By request, here is my routine for exponentiation by squaring modulo a given number. There are some variations that could be done, of course. This version does no error checking on the parameters an does a little bit-twiddling for minor efficiencies.

```
def exp_by_squaring_mod(x, n, mod):
    """Calculate x**n % mod by squaring. This assumes x and n are non-
    negative integers and mod is a positive integer. This returns 1 for
    0**0.
    """
    result = 1
    x %= mod
    # Reduce n and keep constant the value of result * x**n % mod
    while n:  # while n is not zero
        if n & 1:  # n is odd
            result = result * x % mod
        x = x * x % mod
        n >>= 1  # integer divide by 2
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, run time is greatly optimized, but I get a DivisionbyZero error for a = 1000000, b = 1000000 n = 1000000. I am using your very first explanation.

Comment: @CarlsonBimbuh: Perhaps I should have written the theorem in full: `gcd(r, s) = gcd(r % s, x)` unless `s` is zero, then it is `r` (assuming all those values are nonnegative integers). If you really need the correct answer for that case, calculate `a**n + b**n` in full (no modulus), and that is the GCD. It is hard to believe that those values of `a, b, n` are a real problem.

Comment: I'm now a little confused. "exponentiaion by squaring and MODULUS at each step,"  Please, Modulus by what?

Comment: Please sorry for bugging you one more time. I modified my comment, can you please explain again from it? And don't worry, I fully understand what modulus is.

Comment: @CarlsonBimbuh: In your function that calculates exponentiation-by-squaring, each loop will square a value and may multiply two values. In either case, just after the squaring or multiplication, then find the remainder when divided by `a - b`. This will keep the values small and thus speeds up the squarings and multiplications. Do you want me to show you such a routine?

Comment: I will really appreciate if you could show me the routine. That's where am stuck at.

Comment: I have implemented, as your answer suggested, Exponentiation by Squaring, u can check out the function in the question (edit), I will be delighted if you showed me where I should do the modulus (a-b)

Comment: @CarlsonBimbuh: I wrote my routine and posted it before I saw your comment or edit. I am surprised how similar our routines are, but there are a limited number of ways to do this. You can see where I take the modulus in my routine.

Comment: Is there a reason not to simply use the three-argument form of pow?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, you've made my day, I'm glad having you treat my problem, may the Good Lord Jesus bless you. Just one, the very last clarification, if (a-b) == 0, u said I will have to fully calculate the a**n + b**n, does it mean I will just have to remove the % mod in your function (i.e basically just using my own routine.)

Comment: @CarlsonBimbuh: Yes, I suppose if you really may get a modulus of zero then you should have a version without the modulus--but you could just do `a**n + b**n` and let Python do the calculation. You could add that check to my routine--remember that I said my routine, as is, does no error checking but you could add some.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks a lot, A LOT. You have solved my problem, totally and completely!! It even works in less than a second for 1<=a,b,n<=10^15. Thanks a lot, God bless you abundantly and I thank him for letting me encounter you here today. Left for me to check your answer as the best. Thanks a lot Once more.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: the _builtin_ [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow), not `math.pow`.

Comment: @DSM: Oops, I forgot about that one. I'll include it in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to optimize your exponentiation using this method:

```
def powerBySquaring(x,n):
    if n < 0:
        x = 1 / x
        n = -n
    if n == 0: return 1
    y = 1
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            x = x * x
            n = n / 2
        else:
            y = x * y
            x = x * x
            n = (n-1)/2
    return x * y
```